# jquery accordion submenu dropdown

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui

I want to create accordion tabs .I reffered to [this](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-simple-vertical-accordion-menu/) site . I get the following output:

[image]

Actually on click of **Item 1** it should expand and display the sub menus..

but some how the onclick not working and in the navigation bar i get **#** appended to the url..

The below code is jquery function.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
     if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
     $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
     $(this).next().slideToggle();
     $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass('active');
  }
});
```

});

I have added the following scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/development-bundle/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.accordion.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js"></script>
```

Do I need to add more scripts to achive the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check the below link accordion [plugin](http://www.designchemical.com/lab/demo-wordpress-vertical-accordion-menu-plugin/)

If you met any problem check `jQuery` conflict